# How To Use QJson library In Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qjson

Now i am using Qt v2.3
I have one problem, i need to send the data to server by using json but Qjson class is not there.
How to include JSON to Qt? or 
Is there any external header file for that?

Comment: The latest version of Qt is version 5. Are you sure you mean Qt2.3 ?

Comment: Yes, Now i am Using Qt creator  2.3 version

Comment: @user3472783: The Qt Creator version (IDE) is not the Qt version (library). Check what Qt is configured inside Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably referring to the QtCreator version as opposed to the Qt. Qt 2.3 would be very old as a framework version used, and probably most of the third-party libraries would not work with it anymore, anyhow.

Just use Qt 5, and that means switch to it if you had not done so yet.

You will then get access to the [qt json classes in QtCore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) all of a sudden. Basically, you will have access to these classes:

> QJsonArray Encapsulates a JSON array
>
> QJsonDocument Way to read and write JSON documents
>
> QJsonObject Encapsulates a JSON object
>
> QJsonObject::iterator QJsonObject::iterator class provides an STL-style non-const iterator for QJsonObject
>
> QJsonObject::const_iterator QJsonObject::const_iterator class provides an STL-style const iterator for QJsonObject
>
> QJsonParseError Used to report errors during JSON parsing
>
> QJsonValue Encapsulates a value in JSON

Here you can find a very good example about the usage of these classes, more or less:

[JSON Save Game Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html)

If you have the Qt 4 series, or older, you could try to backport these classes if no one had not done so.

The overall advantage of these classes is that they are extremely fast compared to other libraries, like qjson (4-5 times) or even the libjson library written in C! This is possible due to the binary format it uses internally to speed up the read and write operation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, QT = Quick Time, Qt = cute.
You use Qt Creator 2.3, it is your IDE version not your Qt lib version.

Witch version of Qt did you use ? Qt 5.2, 4.7 etc ...

For using QJson correctly, you should copy your QJSON Folder in the same place of your project and include the *.pri in your .pro.

You can found in this link how to use correctly QJson class with your project.

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_QJson_to_easy_manage_JSON_objects_with_Qt

Comment: When i open Qt in Welcome page it shows  (Welcome to Qt Creator2.3) but in Help Page (Qt Creator Manual Version 2.4.1).it means my version is qt 2.3 or not

Comment: i do not  have any Qjson folder, please provide me all the stuff to use json or else please guide me .

Comment: What qjson folder are you talking about and why?

Comment: hi laszlo ,in  above comment @yekmen posted some thing like Qjson Folder, that's why i told . I don't have any like folder .
and PLEASE Explain me, how to use json in qt? Because i started learning Qt just last week an onwards.
i have another Question, which language is best to develop some thing in qt because i saw qt supporting number of language like Pascal, c++, .net . Please explain me about all this things I am requesting to u please help me.

Comment: @user3472783: I was addressing that question at yekmen, not you. As for the on usage, see my answer below. :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Please explain my another Question also , which language is best to  develop the application in qt. And please explain what is differences pons and cons of different languages. I am Requesting to u Please help me

Comment: @user3472783: this site is not for such questions, but people mostly use C++ for Qt development...